# Can´t fetch data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, children

[image]I have been reading about this, but it didn't help at all. I followed a Youtube tutorial and it doesn´t append the right information from stack overflow. How do I append a Array to another Array from a child node?

(It´s a VOCABULARY TEST application).

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://glosormark6macbook-733f1.firebaseio.com/")

    InteUnikaLista = [String]()
    InteUnikaListaB = [String]()

    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    databasehandel = ref.child("Användare").child(uid!).child("Glosförhör").child(String(myIndex)).child("ProjektNamet").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if let Stuff = snapshot.value as? String
        {
            self.navigationItem.title = Stuff
        }
    })
  //  let userReference = ref.child("Användare").child(uid!).child("Glosförhör").child(String(GlosFörhör.count))//Var den går in

    databasehandel = ref.child("Användare").child(uid!).child("Glosförhör").child(String(myIndex)).child("Betydelser").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if let Stuff = snapshot.value as? String
        {
            InteUnikaLista.append(Stuff)
            self.exit.reloadData()
        }
        else
        {
            //går inte ftersom den inte kabn bli String
            print("Error by inte if let")
        }
    })
    databasehandel = ref.child("Användare").child(uid!).child("Glosförhör").child(String(myIndex)).child("Glosor").observe(.value, with:{ snapshot in
        if let Stuff = snapshot.value as? String
        {
            InteUnikaLista.append(Stuff)
            self.exit.reloadData()
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error by inte if let")
        }
    })   
}
```

Comment: what is the issues u r facing..?

Comment: I can´t read in the data from firebase.

Comment: Also when I run it it dosen´t let Stuff =  snapshot.value as? String

Comment: A few things. Please post your Firebase structure as TEXT please, no images. That way if we need to use it in the answer we can copy/paste. You can get the structure from the Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON. Second thing is thing is that we don't know what myIndex is as the code to init that var is not included. databaseHandle doesn't appear to be defined - but moreover it's not used so you don't need it really (in this use case). Finally - I would inspect the ref to ensure it's a valid path.